# Magento 2 : Call cms page in anchor tag

Tags: magento2, cms-pages

I am new in magento2. I saw many question but i can't understand flow.

can any one help me how to call cms page in anchor tag ?

I tried some code but it is not working.

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('footer'); ?>">CMS PAGE LINK</a>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can get url by page ID, Try this flow :-**

```
$pageId = 1;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$cms_page_url = $objectManager->create('Magento\Cms\Helper\Page')
->getPageUrl($pageId);
```

**Add this code in phtml :-**

```
<a href="<php echo $cms_page_url; ?>">CMS PAGE LINK</a>
```

Comment: Happy to help sir ....Happy Coding !!!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

In Magento2, if you want to get url then you use `$block` instead of `$this` in **phtml**

```
<a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('footer'); ?>">CMS PAGE LINK</a>
```

**`$block->getUrl('footer')`** give the result like `SITEURL/footer`

In magento2, you want to get a CMS page url in phtml then you use

```
$_cmsHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Cms\Helper\Page');
$Url =$_cmsHelper->getPageUrl(PAGE_ID);
```

### Additional Info

If you want to get **a cms page url by ID** then you can get `In Block, Helper, Model ,controller` classes then you should use inject in `__construct()`

```
protected $_pageHelper;
public function __construct(

    \Magento\Cms\Helper\Page $pageHelper,

) {
    $this->_pageHelper = $pageHelper;
}

public function getCmsUrl()
{
    retun $this->_pageHelper->getPageUrl($pageId);
}
```